# Dart in Android Studio. No device to run applicaton

Tags: android, android-studio, dart, flutter

I can't run application because there is no devices on the list.
I tried to create AVD and connect real device. I have installed curl, Android SDK path was set, flutter licenses were accepted. I have Ubuntu 16.04.4

Output of `flutter run --verbose` in projects directory :

```
 flutter: command not found
```

I have flutter path:

```
$ export PATH=/home/joe/flutter/bin:$PATH
$ echo $PATH
/home/joe/flutter/bin:home/joe/flutter/bin:home/joe/flutter/bin:/home/joe/bin:/home/joe/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Now I put path's to `.bashrc` and run `source ~/.bashrc`, did I put path's correct way ?

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories

    export PATH=/home/joe/flutter/bin:$PATH
    export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/SDK
    export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
```

After adding path's to `.bashrc` I run `flutter doctor`:

```
$ /home/joe/flutter/bin/flutter doctor

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[!] Flutter (Channel master, v0.5.7-pre.102, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    ✗ Downloaded executables cannot execute on host.
      See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6207 for more information
      On Debian/Ubuntu/Mint: sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
      On Fedora: dnf install libstdc++.i686
      On Arch: pacman -S lib32-libstdc++5

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.io/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set $ANDROID_HOME to that location.
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 4 categories.
```

Comment: The error message doesn't seem to be related to the title of your question. Do you execute `flutter run` in the Flutter install directory? It should be run in the directory where you created your Flutter project. As the error message says, the directory needs to contain a `pubspec.yaml` file. If there is no such file, then you know you are in the wrong directory.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer I tried now and it shows `flutter: command not found`

Comment: Then you need to add the `flutter/bin` directory to your `PATH` like explained in https://flutter.io/setup-macos/#update-your-path (or use one of these links https://flutter.io/get-started/install/ if you use a different OS)

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer I did, see above.

Comment: @JackJ you could also use the flutter doctor utility to test everything is fine.

Comment: What happens if you use `/home/joe/flutter/bin/flutter doctor`?

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer see above.

Comment: Looks good. You need to install a few library as explained in the `flutter doctor` output. `flutter doctor` without the full path should now work as well.

Comment: There is still an issue with `Unable to locate Android SDK.` though. Are you sure it's in /home/joe/Android/SDK`?

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer Yes: it says no SDK, no plugin, no device.

Comment: I saw that. You need to take care of these parts yourself. They are not part of Flutter.

Comment: @ Günter Zöchbauer I'm able to run flutter apps through Android Studio, now, but doctor still shows those messages. Thanks.

Comment: See also https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2084

Answer (score 1):

Can be easily fixed by setting project SDK to latest Android API.

1. Go to File
2. Project Structure
3. Under Project-SDK select the latest SDK installed(Example:- Android API 29 Platform).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set an Environment variable.

You can check it [here](https://www.developerlibs.com/2018/05/flutter-introduction-and-setup.html) for Flutter SDK setup with Android Studio